# Show image on button click for the youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using an image over the youtube video. On the image click (#imageID) the video is shown. Now I have a problem how to stop the video, reverse it back to the start position (0:00) and show image over the video again on the button click (#stop_replace) for example.

HTML:

```
<div id="ytapiplayer2" style="display:none;">
    <object width="600" height="375">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/WSulgIt-Q_c?fs=1&hl=en_US&rel=0&autoplay=1"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/WSulgIt-Q_c?fs=1&hl=en_US&rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="600" height="375"></embed>
    </object>
</div>

<img src="image.jpg" id="imageID" />
<img src="button_image.jpg" id="stop_replace" />
```

JavaScript/Jquery:

```
$('#imageID').click(function() {
$('#ytapiplayer2').show();
$('#imageID').hide();
});
```

The code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AdUvY/6/. I know this also could be done using iframe but I need it implemented in this way. Could you help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample Demo for you.

Please check this and let me know if it gives a solution to your problem.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/Rpgkk/2/

Here I am using jQuery SWFObject Plugin from http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/. This allows us to write simple code to embed SWF Objects.

Also, in IE Browsers if you jus Hide the SWF object, then there is a chance of playing in the background. So, best thing will be remove the complete player from the div, if you don't need that any more.

So, I removed the SWF object from player div when I don't want that.

This automatically allows us to start the player from starting when we need.

Please let me know if it need any modifications.

Comment: Thanks it's what I have been looking for.